# How to "expose" types in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have two compilation units, and one "frontend" file.

In the first compilation unit, I have the following in the `moduleA.mli`:

```
module A : sig
   type t
   ... 
end
```

and in the `moduleA.ml` I have:

```
module A = struct
   type t = float * float
   ... 
end
```

In the second compilation unit, I have the following in the `moduleB.mli`:

```
module B : sig
   type t
   ... 
end
```

and in the `moduleB.ml` I have:

```
open moduleA

module B = struct
   type t = A.t
   ... 
end
```

Now, in the "frontend" file, I get type errors like:

`This expression has type moduleB.B.t but an expression was expected of type moduleA.A.t`

Yet as I've defined them, these should be synonyms (both are `float * float`). How can I "expose" essentially these types so that Ocaml knows they are the same?

Comment: Do you want other modules to know that both are `float * float` or just that both are the same? In other words, do you want the "frontend" to be able to treat `A.t` and `B.t` as tuples or only to be able to use values of `B.t` where `A.t` is expected (and vice versa)?

Comment: @sepp2k The latter. It doesn't need to know that they are tuples (I have functions which can operate on them) but I'd like for it to know that `B.t` and `A.t` are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you split a module into a signature and an implementation, only the information in the signature can be used by other modules and anything else is private to the implementation. So when other modules look at your modules `A` and `B`, all they see is `type t` and another `type t` and they have no idea that those refer to the same type.

If you want to expose the information that `A.t = B.t`, that information needs to be part of the signature. So simply change `type t` in the signature of `B` to `type t = A.t` and now this equality will be part of the module's public interface and can be relied on by other modules.